# Ruby SSO, CAS, oauth, userstore. What options do I have?

Tags: php, ruby, authentication, single-sign-on, cas

Q: How would you create a **SSO**? What would you do about **authentication** (separate app or same as sso) and **user store**?

Background info:

> We have 40+ php apps, java apps and
>   Ruby apps.
>
> Currently, we have a custom
>   SSO+authentication solution. It's an
>   app written in php that is now used as
>   SSO, while supporting
>   email/username/phone-number + password
>   as authentication. It works, but was
>   built for a few apps only, not
>   originally meant to be the SSO -
>   solution. It doesn't have a usable view, every app create their own login/register forms and use the API. They share context and we'd like a more universal design.
>
> Now we know want to support Oauth and
>   openid solutions, as facebook connect,
>   google and more, (or do we really?), in addition to
>   existing authentications. We can
>   expand existing php-solution, but we
>   are considering alternatives.

If you were to do all this in Ruby, what would you do?

Some additional info:

- All users exist in SSO, today.

  - The company does aquire other companies/systems at times, having their own users. Would you migrate or create some kind of mapper?
- Customers in a Microsoft CRM, but I consider this unrelated. Or do I?
- I've shallowly looked at RubyCAS and ClassyCAS, and don't know if they are suitable. Is CAS the way to go?
- Would you keep going with php? What would you use?

As you see, I have a lot of questions. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

I a previous job we used [Jasig CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) for SSO (several apps in Java and Python). After getting over some quirks in the configuration and my dislike of all things Java, it actually worked pretty well. At the time I found the [wiki](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/Home) to be a valuable resource, but things might have changed in the last year.

Authentication was handled via a separate app (custom) using an OpenLDAP directory that was preinitialized with a script that got user info out of an AD server.

Regarding the actual server you might actually want to use the Jasig one, IIRC it's the reference implementation and is easy to [customize via a Maven overlay](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Maintaining+local+customizations+using+Maven+2).

Comment: thx for the answer. We don't need LDAP, luckily. I hope I get answers not proposing java, I left it and don't want to look back, but I appreciate the proposal.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby-cas](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/) FTW.